# App is crashing when moving to other app and then moving back

Tags: ios, memory-management, rect

I have an issue with my app..
It's crashing when i'm using home button for multitasking to move to another app and when i want to go back again to my app it's crashing and i get the message:

```
*** -[UIView convertRect:toView:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x81e4020
```

It started since i've implemented "inner-view" ad's.
do i need to do something in my code to make it disspapear?
I tried to solve it but no success.
This is my code of the ad's:

```
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 50);
    self.adBanner = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.view convertRect:adBanner.frame toView:nil];   --->This is a line i tried to put...
    [self.view addSubview:self.adBanner];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iaAdReceived:) name:@"iaAdReceived" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iaDefaultAdReceived:) name:@"iaDefaultAdReceived" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iaAdFailed:) name:@"IaAdFailed" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iaAdClicked:) name:@"IaAdClicked" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iaAdWillShow:) name:@"IaAdWillShow" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iaAdDidShow:) name:@"IaAdDidShow" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iaAdWillHide:) name:@"IaAdWillHide" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iaAdDidHide:) name:@"IaAdDidHide" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iaAdWillClose:) name:@"IaAdWillClose" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iaAdDidClose:) name:@"IaAdDidClose" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iaAdWillResize:) name:@"IaAdWillResize" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iaAdDidResize:) name:@"IaAdDidResize" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iaAdWillExpand:) name:@"IaAdWillExpand" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iaAdDidExpand:) name:@"IaAdDidExpand" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iaAppShouldSuspend:) name:@"IaAppShouldSuspend" object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iaAppShouldResume:) name:@"IaAppShouldResume" object:nil];

    // Display ad
    if (![InneractiveAd DisplayAd:@"iOS_Test" withType:IaAdType_Banner withRoot:self.adBanner withReload:60 withParams:optionalParams])
    {
        [adBanner removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

    -(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
    {
            [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
            [adBanner removeFromSuperview];
    }

- (IBAction)iaAdReceived:(id)sender
   {
       // The ad view has finished loading a paid ad
   }

    - (IBAction)iaDefaultAdReceived:(id)sender
    {
        // The ad view has finished loading a default ad
    }

    - (IBAction)iaAdFailed:(id)sender
    {
        // The ad view has failed to load an ad
    }

    - (IBAction)iaAdClicked:(id)sender
    {
        // The ad has been clicked
    }

    - (IBAction)iaAdWillShow:(id)sender
    {
        // The ad is about to show
    }

    - (IBAction)iaAdDidShow:(id)sender
    {
        // The ad did show
    }

    - (IBAction)iaAdWillHide:(id)sender
    {
        // The ad is about to hide
    }

    - (IBAction)iaAdDidHide:(id)sender
    {
        // The ad did hide
    }

    - (IBAction)iaAdWillClose:(id)sender
    {
        // The ad is about to close
    }

    - (IBAction)iaAdDidClose:(id)sender
    {
        // The ad did close
    }

    - (IBAction)iaAdWillResize:(id)sender
    {
        // The ad is about to resize
    }

    - (IBAction)iaAdDidResize:(id)sender
    {
        // The ad did resize
    }

    - (IBAction)iaAdWillExpand:(id)sender
    {
        // The ad is about to expand
    }

    - (IBAction)iaAdDidExpand:(id)sender
    {
        // The ad did expand
    }

    - (IBAction)iaAppShouldSuspend:(id)sender
    {
        // The app should suspend (for example, when the ad expands)
    }

    - (IBAction)iaAppShouldResume:(id)sender
    {
        // The app should resume (for example, when the ad collapses)
    }
```

I attached a screenshot...
What could it be?
Thanks...

[image: Error]

Comment: Suddenly i noticed that when i add the viewWillDisappear in comment everything seem to work: -(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [adBanner removeFromSuperview];
} very weird... but maybe you have a idea why?

Comment: If you want to test existing the app and re entering it, run your app to the device, then when it's done building hit command-. To stop the build. From there try launching your app again and it may work, sometimes Xcode debugging an app moving between these states can cause the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when running :

```
[self.view convertRect:adBanner.frame toView:nil];
```

your view doesn't exists anymore.

in your appDelegate you should work on this method :

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
 */
}
```

anyway, what did you try to achieve with this line ? because it's returning a CGRect which you're not using.

Comment: Thanks moxy.. actually i thought that this line solved the problem but later i saw that it didn't. now i know that it because the viewWillDisappear method... don't know yet why. i want to hide the banner when i move to a different view but it's crashing my app :\